# python loop OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')

Tags: python, macos

python 2.5 on osx

I got the OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large') for the following code:

```
x = 1.04
for i in range(2, 101):
  x += x**i
print x
```

So instead, I used the code below; no error was generated.

```
x = 0
for i in range(1, 101):
  x += 1.04**i
print x
```

The result is 1287.12865279 and this seems miles away from the maximum float. If I need to use a different type to handle this floating point calculation, why does the latter code work while the former one doesn't? I'm puzzled..... Any help&explanation on resolving the error would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, you are setting x to the result of your calculation. You use that x as the base the next loop, instead of 1.04. Thus, the values become very large very soon.

Before the result becomes too large, x has the following values:

```
2.1216
11.6713174057
18567.4643593
2.2068000989e+21
1.15498932026e+128
```